# Checking if value in linked list is equal to String at each node

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a program for a homework assignment that has a binary search tree (Roster) that Student objects are inserted to by their String Id. Each student has a linked list that their courses are added to containing the String of the course and their grade. The binary search tree is my own version of an implementation.

I'm having trouble implementing my method to print the students that all contain a specific course. I think my implementation is off in my printCourseHelper() method as the if condition isn't working properly to check if the value in the list at each node is equal to the given value.

I'm looking for all student's enrolled in the course "Math161" which should be 3, and the String ID's of the student's in that class would be printed. I'm not getting any errors when I run my program, however only the functions being called above my displayStudents()  are printing.

My issues I believe are in my BST.java, printCourse and printCourseHelper methods:

```
public void printCourse(String course) {
        printCourseHelper(root, course);
    }

    public void printCourseHelper(Node n, String course) {        
        if(n.element.getCourseList().contains(course)) {
            System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
        }

        if (n.left != null) {
            printCourseHelper(n.left, course);
        }    
        if (n.right != null) {
            printCourseHelper(n.right, course);
        }     
    }
```

Homework5.class / main:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Homework5 {

    static Roster rost = new Roster();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addStudent();
        displayAllStudents();
        lookupStudent("11114");
        addCourse();
        displayStudents("Math161");
    }

    // add students to the roster
    static void addStudent() {
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11111", "Jon", "Benson"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11112", "Erick", "Hooper"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11113", "Sam", "Shultz"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11114", "Trent", "Black"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11115", "Michell", "Waters"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11116", "Kevin", "Johnson"));
    }

    // display all students in the roster
    static void displayAllStudents() {
        rost.displayAllStudents();
    }

    // lookup a student in the roster
    static void lookupStudent(String id) {
        if (rost.find(id) != null) {
            System.out.println(id + " found");
        } else {
            System.out.println(id + " not found");
        }
    }

    // add courses to the roster
    static void addCourse() {
        rost.addCourse("11111", new Course("CS116", 80));
        rost.addCourse("11111", new Course("Math161", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("Math161", 70));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("CS146", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("CS105", 85));
        rost.addCourse("11113", new Course("CS216", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("CIS255", 75));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("CS216", 80));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("Math161", 60));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("COMM105", 90));
    }

    // display students enrolled in a given course id
    static void displayStudents(String courseId) {
        rost.displayStudents(courseId);
    }

    // display courses taken by a student
    static void displayCourses(String id) {
        rost.displayCourses("id");
    }

    // display the average grade for a student
    static void getCourseAverage(String courseId) {
        rost.getCourseAverage(courseId);
    }

    // display the average grade for a student
    static void dropCoursesBelow(String id, int grade) {
        rost.dropCoursesBelow(id, grade);
    }

    // drop a course from a student
    static void dropCourse(String id, String courseId) {
        rost.dropCourse(id, courseId);
    }

    // change the grade for a student
    static void changeGrade(String id, String courseId, int grade) {
        rost.changeGrade(id, courseId, grade);
    }
}
```

Student.class

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName; 
    LinkedList<Course> courses = new LinkedList<>();

    Student(String id, String fName, String lName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setName(String lName) {
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student other) {    
        return this.getId().compareTo(other.getId());
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        courses.add(course);
    }

    public LinkedList<Course> getCourseList() {
        return courses;
    } 
}
```

Course.class:

```
class Course {

    LinkedList<Course> course = new LinkedList<>();   
    String id;  // course id
    int grade;

    Course(String id, int grade) {
        this.id = id;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getCourseId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setId(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

}
```

Roster.class:

```
class Roster {

    Student root;
    int numStudents;
    BST<Student> roster = new BST<>();
    LinkedList<Course> courseList = new LinkedList<>();

    public Roster() {
        root = null;
        numStudents = 0;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student st) {
        roster.insert(st);
        numStudents++;
    }

    public void displayAllStudents() {
        roster.traverse(2);
    }

    public Student find(String id) {
        return roster.find(id);
    }

    public void addCourse(String id, Course course) {
        Student student = roster.find(id);
        student.addCourse(course);      
    }

    public void displayStudents(String courseId) {
        roster.printCourse(courseId);
    }
}
```

BST.java

```
class BST<Roster extends Comparable> {

    private Node root;

    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }

    // Generic find method
    public Student find(String id) {  
        Node current = root;
        // Loop until e.compare to current element is not equal to 0
        while (id.compareTo(current.element.getId()) != 0) {
            //!!! implement
            // if e.compare is less than 0 set current to current.left
            if (id.compareTo(current.element.getId()) < 0) {
                current = current.left;
            } // else if current is 0 or greater than 0 set current 
            // to current.right
            else {
                current = current.right;
            }
            // if current is null, return null
            if (current == null) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // return current value when loop ends
        return current.element;    
    }

    public void insert(Student st) {
        Node newNode = new Node(st);
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            Node current = root;
            Node parent = null;
            while (true) {
                parent = current;
                if (st.getId().compareTo(current.element.getId()) < 0) {
                    current = current.left;
                    if (current == null) {
                        parent.left = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    current = current.right;
                    if (current == null) {
                        parent.right = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printCourse(String course) {
        printCourseHelper(root, course);
    }

    public void printCourseHelper(Node n, String course) {
        if(n.element.getCourseList().contains(course)) {
            System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
        }
        if (n.left != null) {
            printCourseHelper(n.left, course);
        }
        if (n.right != null) {
            printCourseHelper(n.right, course);
        }   
    }

    public void traverse(int traverseType) {
        switch (traverseType) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("\nPreorder traversal: ");
                // call preOrder(root) and implement preOrder()
                preOrder(root);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("\nList of all students:  ");
                inOrder(root);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("\nPostorder traversal: ");
                // call postOrder(root) and implement postOrder()
                postOrder(root);
                break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void inOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            inOrder(localRoot.left);
            System.out.print(localRoot.element.getId() + " ");
            inOrder(localRoot.right);
        }
    }

    private void preOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
            preOrder(localRoot.left);
            preOrder(localRoot.right);
        }
    }

    private void postOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            postOrder(localRoot.left);
            postOrder(localRoot.right);
            System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
        }
    }
}

class Node {

    protected Student element;
    protected Node left;
    protected Node right;

    public Node(Student st) {
        element = st;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `n.element.returnList().contains(course)` does? From what I can see, `n.element` should be `Student` but it doesn't seem to have a method `returnList()`. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: n.element should be Student, and it should be getCourseList() not return list, forgot to edit that. The if condition should check the student at the current node and if they contain the course in it's linked list that is being checked for, and print all students in that course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to see if a LinkedList of type Course contains a String. The contains method for LinkedList takes an Object as it's parameter type and that is why you are not getting a compilation issue.

The below code snippet is never true because a Course will never equal a String. I mention equal here because internally the LinkedList contains method checks equality for the Object you pass in against the Objects it contains.

```
if(n.element.returnList().contains(course)) {
    System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
}
```

***Possible Solution using Map***

Change courses to be a Map in Student class and then change the IF statement to check if the Map contains an element based on the course name. If the Map contains an object then it's true that the Student takes this course.

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Map<String, Course> courses = new HashMap<>();

    Student(String id, String fName, String lName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setName(String lName) {
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student other) {
        return this.getId().compareTo(other.getId());
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        courses.put(course.getId(), course);
    }

    public Map<String, Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
}
```

IF statement

```
if(n.element.getCourses().get(course) != null) {
    System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
}
```

***Possible Solution using List***

Add new method to Student class.

```
 public boolean takesCourse(String courseName){
        for(Course course : courses){
            if(courseName.equals(course.getId)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

IF statement

```
if(n.element.takesCourse(course)) {
    System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
}
```

Comment: So how do I go about implementing this method to check the linked list at the current node, and check if it contains the course that is being searched for ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a possible solution. I know this is a homework assignment for you so I would really recommend reading up on why the solution works with a Map

Comment: Yeah I don't think I can use a map, he strictly states in the assignment that course should use either LinkedList or ArrayList only.

Comment: If you strictly need to use a List then add a method to the Student class which takes the name of a course as an input parameter and returns a boolean. The method should iterate over all courses in the list and return true if the input course is equal to a courses id and return false if no course's id matches the desired course name. Your IF statement would then be something like n.element.takesCourse(course)

Comment: @Devin .. I added an example of a solution using a List.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169194/discussion-between-ggolding-and-devin).